# Create url with out the port number in Weblogic

Tags: redirect, weblogic, port

I have one weblogic server in our production environment. Server admin console is running on port 7001. I want to hide the port number from users without changing it. I have set the DNS record. Now console can access as:

```
http://pordserver:7001/console
```

But it should be

```
http://pordserver/console
```

Weblogic server version is 10.3

Comment: This is a pretty good breakdown of your options: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1075189?tstart=0 Use the default port 80/443, or put something in front of weblogic

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I saw this link but some website introduce a way. Ref : `http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/19/virtual-hosts-configuration-with-weblogic-server/` But this not work in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do This By Using Virtual Hosting

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/19/virtual-hosts-configuration-with-weblogic-server/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  This is more of comment than an answer.  If you could include the steps in your answer, you have a better chance of getting an upvote.